# Searching Textfiles for dates

Tags: vb.net, date, listbox, text-files

I have created a text file with dates and products bought on that date. I want to read the file when a button is clicked and the return the products bought on the current date only (todays date) into a listbox in VB.net . Any help appreciated.

This is an example of my textfile.

```
06:35 Sunday, 15 March 2015

Corona Bottle
Miller Bottle
Bulmers Bottle
Beamish Pint
Bacon Fries
Orange Juice

06:41 Sunday, 15 March 2015

Murphy's Pint
Bulmers Pint
Tayto
Purple Snack
```

This is the code that i have  so far:

```
Private Sub btnTodaysTrans_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTodaysTrans.Click
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("ProductsSold.txt")
    lstTodaysTrans.Items.Clear()
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        lstTodaysTrans.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mind to show us some sample lines and what you have tried to extract them?

Comment: not as comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

try using the textparser for your operation.it will be like

```
            dim field as string
            dim date as datetime
        If File.Exists(yourfilename) Then
            Using parser As New TextFieldParser(yourfilename)
                parser.SetDelimiters(vbTab)
                While Not parser.EndOfData
                    fields = parser.ReadFields()
                  if IsDate(fields) Then
                    date= DateTime.ParseExact(fields, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                    if date.value<> your condition Then
                        '' what you want
                    else
                        ''what you want
                    end if
                  end if
                end while
        end if
```

**NOTE**

Or else You can use the error encountered while converting the text files to datetime as condition for checking if it is a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

First, that is a bad way to store your data. The best way is a database. But even if you use a text-file you could use a better approach. Because the file contains empty line and also different lines belong logically together. So you need to find the date of every product in the previous lines. You could add it to every line, then it's easier.

However, you can use following code which uses LINQ and a loop:

```
Dim format = "dd MMMM yyyy"
Dim dateProducts As New List(Of Tuple(Of Date, String))
Dim lines = From line In File.ReadLines("ProductsSold.txt")
            Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
            Select line.Trim()
For Each line As String In lines
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim isDateline As Boolean = False
    If line.Length >= format.Length AndAlso line.Contains(","c) Then
        ' try to extract the date...
        Dim tokens = line.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        isDateline = Date.TryParseExact(tokens.Last().Trim(), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, currentDate)
    End If
    If isDateline Then
        dateProducts.Add(New Tuple(Of Date, String)(currentDate, Nothing))
    ElseIf dateProducts.Count > 0 Then
        ' select date from last item and add this product
        dateProducts.Add(New Tuple(Of Date, String)(dateProducts.Last().Item1, line))
    Else
        ' otherwise invalid data, product without date, skip
    End If
Next
```

Now you could use `ToLookup` to create something similar to a dictionary, the key is the date(without time) and the value is the list of products for that date. One difference to a dictionary is that you get an empty sequence if there is no product for a given date.

```
Dim dateLookup = dateProducts.
    Where(Function(ds) ds.Item2 IsNot Nothing).
    ToLookup(Function(ds) ds.Item1.Date)

Dim allProductsOfToday = dateLookup(Date.Today)
For Each dateProductInfo In allProductsOfToday
    lstTodaysTrans.Items.Add(dateProductInfo.Item2) ' Item2 is the product
Next
```

I have tested it with your sample file which doesn't contain products for today, so it's not the best example. If you change one of both date from `15 March 2015` to `16 March 2015` you see the appropriate products in the `ListBox`.

Comment: We have to use this method of data store as it is specified in our college project unfortunately.                                                                         Do we copy this code together or are these two different methods to fetch the transactions made today? I understand the date lookup code but find the first For/Next loop code in your comment a little hard to follow. But just need to know do they both need to be used together in order for it to work?

Comment: @VB123: you can store the final `dateLookup` as a public property so that you can reuse it if the file doesn't change often. But the first loop is needed to fill the list which is used as source for the lookup. What part do you find difficult to understand? The LINQ query that i use before the loop is not needed, you could also do that in the loop. I have just used it to filter out empty lines.